# How to calculate Mean Bias Error(MBE) in Python?

Tags: python, numpy, scikit-learn, statistics

I am trying to calculate **Mean Bias Error**(**MBE**) for a set of actual and test prediction in Python. I looked in sklearn.metrics library or NumPy, but there is no method listed to calculate it.

Can anyone suggest any library or a way for how to calculate it?

Thanks,
Debayan

Comment: I don't know of any library, but maybe this code helps you develop the metric. Its the same structure, but different formula: https://github.com/TheAlgorithms/Python/blob/master/machine_learning/scoring_functions.py#L109

Answer (score 3):

MBE is defined as a mean value of differences between predicted and true values so you can calculate it using simple mean difference between two data sources:

```
import numpy as np
data_true = np.random.randint(0,100,size=100)
data_predicted = np.random.randint(0,100,size=100) - 50
MBE = np.mean(data_predicted - data_true) #here we calculate MBE
```

Please note that I've substracted 50 from the predicted value simply to be able to observe that the prediction is in fact biased against the true value.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't found a library to calculate it either, but you can try this :

```
def MBE(y_true, y_pred):
    '''
    Parameters:
        y_true (array): Array of observed values
        y_pred (array): Array of prediction values

    Returns:
        mbe (float): Biais score
    '''
    y_true = np.array(y_true)
    y_pred = np.array(y_pred)
    y_true = y_true.reshape(len(y_true),1)
    y_pred = y_pred.reshape(len(y_pred),1)   
    diff = (y_true-y_pred)
    mbe = diff.mean()
    print('MBE = ', mbe)
```

Answer (score 1):

As Mean Bias Error formula is :
[Mean Bias Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pZYBd.png)

You can deal it like this :

```
import numpy as np

def mean_bias_error(true, pred):
    mbe_loss = np.sum(true - pred)/true.size
    return mbe_loss
```

or

```
def mean_bias_error(true, pred):
    mbe_loss = np.mean(true - pred)
    return mbe_loss
```